# The Definitive Guide (6ed) error?

Tags: javascript

```
/*
* Copy the enumerable properties of p to o, and return o.
* If o and p have a property by the same name, o's property is overwritten.
* This function does not handle getters and setters or copy attributes.
*/
 function extend(o, p) {
       for(prop in p) { // For all props in p.
           o[prop] = p[prop]; // Add the property to o.
      }
      return o;
}



/*
* Return a new object that holds the properties of both o and p.
* If o and p have properties by the same name, the values from o are used.
*/
     function union(o,p) { return extend(extend({},o), p); }
```

I think for **union**, he meant "values from p are used".

I did the test on Chrome. Am I wrong? Sorry. I tend to be very caution when I am learning, especially this is the #1 book for Javascript, and 6ed is recent.

> var o = {x:1}
>
> var p = {x: 2}
>
> function extend(o,p){
>
> ```
> for(prop in p)
>     o[prop] = p[prop];
> return o;
> ```
>
> }
>
> function union(o,p){
>
> ```
> return extend(extend({},o),p);
> ```
>
> var g = union(o,p)
>
> g.x
>
> 2

Thank you.

Comment: You can submit the errata here: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596805531

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah it should read the properties from `p` are kept and `o` are overwritten.

Though when writing this code it is a little safer to do this:

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // now you know it is actually a property on obj and not inherited from elsewhere
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flannigan's book is considered the "[least bad](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#books)" book on javascript, so use with caution. For example, in the *extend* function the variable *prop* is not declared and the following:

```
for(prop in p) { // For all props in p.
    o[prop] = p[prop]; 
}
```

should really include a *hasOwnProperty* test, otherwise it will copy inherited enumerable properties also:

```
for (var prop in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      o[prop] = p[prop]; 
    }
}
```

And yes, the term "union" is probaby misleading to anyone who tries to apply set theory rigorously to objects. If *o* already has a property with the same name as one on *p*, then it will be assigned the same value as the one on *p* (effectively overwriting the value of the one on *o*).

I think he is trying to show that existing properties of *o* that don't have equivalents on *p* are not changed or deleted.